# Most interesting tags?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, data-analysis, community-data

Has anyone done the data mining to discover which tags the most users have marked 'interesting' (or 'interesting' minus 'ignored') for the stacker sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of "interesting" tags for an individual user is not available in the data dump. However, the set of "starred" questions *is* available, so one could derive some set of interesting tags from that data.